# BIRT Report: Using Row value as parameter to Java method

Tags: java, birt

I have a Data Cell in a table with the following expression:

```
Messages.getString(
    ServiceConfigHandler.getInstance().getStatusDesc(row["STATUS"]), 
    reportContext.getLocale())
```

I've made the proper package imports in the DataSet beforeOpen() script clause.

This expression is supposed to take the **row["STATUS"]** value to get the description value from a list, then get the string value based on the locale. Problem is I get a nullPointerException when I try to run the report.

If I use the expression:

```
row["STATUS"]
```

or if I use a **static value in the original expression** like

```
Messages.getString(
    ServiceConfigHandler.getInstance().getStatusDesc("60"), 
    reportContext.getLocale())
```

the report executes normally and no nullPointerException is thrown. First one gets me the number as a string, and the second gets me the desired description of the status number.

Can someone help?

**EDIT:** I had a problem with the XML parsing since the statuses were read from an xml file once and stored in a map in the application scope. restarted the application and it works.

Comment: RE "restarted the application and it works" - so you are no longer looking for an answer?